# jupyter crashes without error message when using tkinter and sklearn KMeans

Tags: python, tkinter, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, k-means

I have a simple user interface with tkinter that works perfectly fine. However, when I import another python module, whenever I use the button that calls this specific line of code (the second one):

```
from tkinter.filedialog import *
files = askopenfilenames()
```

(which works fine normally and even gets the files etc...) Jupyter notebook crashes without any error message, making it hard to understand what the problem is. After investigating, I discovered that this error happens because in the other module that I import in this interface file, there is this import:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

When I comment out this import in the other module and try again, the button event works fine and allows me to select files. However, when I uncomment that import line again, the same problem happen.

Since there is no error message, it is hard to understand the problem and I searched but couldn't find any known problem between KMeans and this Tkinter function. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the lack of error message, it was impossible to find the exact cause of the problem. Suspecting a conflict in libraries, I created a new environment and installed libraries again. If anyone faces a similar issue, I suggest using conda to install libraries instead of pip as much as possible, and only use pip when no other choice is present.